# Python script does not run from crontab

Tags: python, bash, shell, cron

I have the following shell script. It checks whether the python script is running or not, and if not, it will start the python script.
When I run it from command line like ./crontab.sh it works even from other places like MaskRCNN/crontab.sh. But when I put it into the crontab only the echos are working.

```
#!/bin/bash
out=$(ps aux | grep 'python train/train.py' | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1| rev | wc -l)
if [ $out -eq "2" ];then
    echo "2 processes" >> /tmp/testing.txt
else
    echo "1 process" >> /tmp/testing.txt;
    cd /hdd1/Alex/testMaskRCNN_human_bodyparts/MaskRCNN_body;
    CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 /usr/bin/python train/train.py
fi
```

The crontab looks like this:

```
* * * * * /hdd1/Alex/testMaskRCNN_human_bodyparts/MaskRCNN_body/crontab.sh
```

I hope there are enough details. 
Thank you

Comment: `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 /usr/bin/python train/train.py` is this supposed to run the script? because if it is i think the script needs to be surrounded by backticks

Comment: permission issue? might be chmod 777 crontab.sh  would work

Comment: @Nullman Just tried that and it doesn't help :(

Comment: @ggupta neither that doesn't work

Comment: does you `/tmp/testing.txt` get updated with 1's?

Comment: @Nullman yes, it does

Comment: i stll think this line `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 /usr/bin/python train/train.py` is wrong. can you break it into two? `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 ;` and `/usr/bin/python /full/path/to/train/train.py `

Comment: just to make sure we covered all the bases, `train.py` doesn't just print to stdout does it? because if it does you wont see the output

Comment: @Nullman i broke the line into two but did not help. It does print but I am checking if the process is alive by ps -ef | grep train/train.py

Comment: Are there environment variables set for your login that you program needs? Cron doesn't run all the start up scripts that an interactive login runs.

Comment: @GreenMatt you are right! I had to add export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ to my script. that was missing

Comment: @FlorentinAlexandruIftimie: Glad you got it figured out. Please consider entering an answer (and marking it as the accepted answer) so that it is easier for someone with a similar problem to find what worked for you (comments aren't meant to be permanent, fyi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to debug it by adding the &>> operator.

```
`(/usr/bin/python /hdd1/Alex/testMaskRCNN_human_bodyparts/MaskRCNN_body/train/train.py &>> /tmp/testing.txt)`
```

And I found out that it missed an export:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
```

Final script:

```
#!/bin/bash
out=$(ps aux | grep '/usr/bin/python /hdd1/Alex/testMaskRCNN_human_bodyparts/MaskRCNN_body/train/train.py' | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev | wc -l)
if [ $out -eq "2" ];then
    echo "2 processes" >> /tmp/testing.txt
else
    echo "1 process" >> /tmp/testing.txt
    export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
    `(/usr/bin/python /hdd1/Alex/testMaskRCNN_human_bodyparts/MaskRCNN_body/train/train.py &>> /tmp/testing.txt)`
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

try change `train/train.py` to full path...

Comment: try also add ` >  /tmp/cron.log` for loging output